# ¿Cómo INSERT INTO tabla1 (SELECT * FROM tabla2, "valor") en una query?

Tags: mysql

Digamos que tengo estas dos tablas, quiero insertar valores de tabla1 en tabla2 y también tengo que actualizar la columna de estatus, todo en la misma query.

```
       TABLA1                                TABLA2
|-------------------|       |-------------------|-------------------|
|      valor1       |       |      valorX       |      estatus      |
|-------------------|       |-------------------|-------------------|
|         1         |       |         1         |     FINALIZADO    |
|         3         |       |         3         |     FINALIZADO    |
|         2         |       |         2         |     FINALIZADO    |
|         8         |       |         8         |                   |
|        ...        |       |        ...        |        ...        |
|-------------------|       |-------------------|-------------------|
```

Necesito **algo como esto:**

```
INSERT INTO TABLA2 (valorX, estatus)
(SELECT * FROM TABLA1, "FINALIZADO");
```

Me da error 1064, error en sintaxis...

Me gustaría **NO** utilizar los nombres de la TABLA1 porque son tablas muy grandes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sintáxis sería:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA2 (valorX, estatus)
VALUES (SELECT *, "FINALIZADO" FROM TABLA1);
```

o

```
INSERT INTO TABLA2 (valorX, estatus)
SELECT *, "FINALIZADO" 
FROM TABLA1
```

Comment: Me gustaría NO utilizar los nombres de la TABLA1, alguna otra solución? Pero gracias por tú respuesta.

Comment: @lukas Si, cambia el nombre de valor1  por `*`

Comment: Super! Gracias por tú ayuda!

Comment: @lukas de nada, me alegra haber sido de ayuda. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Te sobran los paréntesis, y habría que validar el número de columnas que tiene TABLA1, sólo podría ser una ya que estás insertando dos columnas y una es un valor fijo "FINALIZADO".
La sintaxis correcta sería

```
    INSERT INTO TABLA_DESTINO (COLUMNA_1_DESTINO, COLUMNA_2_DESTINO,... COLUMNA_N_DESTINO) 
    SELECT VALOR_1, VALOR_2...VALOR_N FROM TABLA_ORIGEN
```

En tu caso, algo similar a

```
INSERT INTO TABLA2 (valorX, estatus)
SELECT columna1_tabla1, "FINALIZADO" FROM TABLA1;
```

Si necesitaras insertar en TABLA2 todas las columnas de TABLA1 además de un valor fijo "FINALIZADO", siendo esta columna la última de la tabla, podrías hacerlo así:

```
insert into TABLA2 select t.*, 'FINALIZADO' from tabla1 t
```

Comment: Gracias por tú respuesta.. es posible no utilizar los nombres de columnas de la TABLA1 ?